# Ubuntu on Dell Optiplex 745? Install problems?

Tags: boot, dell, bios

I have a Dell Optiplex 745
Intel Core2Quad Q6600
Legacy BIOS - No UEFI
8 GB of DDR2

I have Ubuntu 18.10 Installed, it boots, but I want to update, but it’s telling me it can’t.

So I decided to start fresh, but whenever I try to boot from the USB, it’s like it’s booting from CD and it doesn’t work, goes to FreeDOS instead for some reason. I am using RUFUS, maybe I’m doing something wrong, but I can’t seem to figure it out. I am following the instructions, but I must be missing part of the puzzle here.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO you are using to make the USB device? I suggest you do and remake and or re download the ISO and remake the USB. You also have not said what version of Ubuntu you are trying to install, a good bit of info that should be in the question.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 *release-upgraded* to 19.04 or the next release (*Ubuntu releases upgrade to the next release, except for LTS releases have a choice of upgrade to next release or next non-LTS*) so your *release-upgrade* is gone.  You can re-install (you didn't say if desktop/server, but desktop without touching files & having *manually installed* packages re-installed automatically IF available for new release in Ubuntu repositories), and FYI: I used 8 various dell optiplex 755 & 745 boxes in QA for all releases.

Comment: I attempted to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS. I used RUFUS and balnaetcher, which I think might have been the problem. I changed to Universal USB Installer and while attempting to make a bootable Manjaro USB and that ended up working, I’ll be trying the same thing later with Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)